# math.pow() is not working and seems to be fine

Tags: java, math

Hi guys I have the following code and is retuning an exception saying "double cannot be converted to String"; to me everything looks fine but dont know if i missing something.
 thanks;

```
            double operadorD=this.nAleatoreo.nextInt(9);
            double operandoD=this.nAleatoreo.nextInt(3); 
            double potencia =Math.pow(operadorD, operandoD);
            generaRespuestas(Integer.parseInt(potencia));
            break;
```

*generaRespuesta receives an int, thats why i converte it to int.

Comment: What type of argument does `Integer.parseInt()` take?

Comment: The code isn't "returning an exception" - you've got a compile-time error. It's important to understand the difference between compile-time errors and exceptions (which are thrown at execution time by code which compiled...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseInt takes a string. If you want to convert from double to int, parseInt is not the way.  One way, (loss of precision aside) is to simply cast it.

```
generaRespuestas((int)potencia);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is because [`Integer#parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) takes a [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) which is not an `int`. However, you could certainly cast the result of [`Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) to an `int` (with corresponding loss of precision).

```
int potencia = (int) Math.pow(operadorD, operandoD);
generaRespuestas(potencia);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the difference now.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt()` : expects a string argument. But `Math.pow()` is returning you `double`

change

`double potencia =Math.pow(operadorD, operandoD);`

to

`int potencia =(int)Math.pow(operadorD, operandoD);`